# Umbraco: Handling In Page Javascript in Uswe Controls

Tags: asp.net, javascript, umbraco

I have quite a number of user controls that I need to embed in Umbraco macros.  Each user control has quite a bit of in page javascript that needs loaded into the page.

I have been building up the javascript with StringBuilder.Appendline then registering a startup script with code behind but this stinks and I feel there has to be a better way of going about this.

Has anyone any ideas please?

Thanks,

B

Answer (score 1):

If the javascript isn't dynamic, that is that it changes based on the usercontrol you would probably be best to extract it and put it in either one .js file for the site or in a number of them.  Doing so allows it to be cached by the browser.

If it is dynamic then I would personally keep it isolated inside the control rather than try to write it out all at once.  I don't believe there is any major performance hit from having several script blocks, although I could be wrong.